# Trying to remove functionality on an element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove "functionality" on one of my elements.

This is the html/php that generates the code:

```
        <table>
        <?php for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){ ?>
            <tr>
                <?php for($k = 0; $k < 10; $k++) {?>
                    <td>asd</td>
                <?php }?>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
            $("td:not(done)").click(function(){
                $(this).addClass("done");
                if(blue){
                    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
                    blue = false;
                } else {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
                    blue = true;
                }
            });
```

Trying to add a class to the td element that has been clicked so it does not work after first click. But can't make it work.

Comment: Do you want TDs to be clickable only once? It is not clear for me what you are exactly looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

updated code

use [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

```
$("td").click(function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('done')) {
        $(this).addClass("done");
        if (blue) {
            $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
            blue = false;
        } else {
            $(this).css("background-color", "red");
            blue = true;
        }
    }
});
```

You forgot to add `.` in  `done` class

[class-selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) documentation

```
$("td:not(.done)").click(function(){
          ^
                $(this).addClass("done");
                if(blue){
                    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
                    blue = false;
                } else {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
                    blue = true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: will not work as the handler is already registered to the element, any attribute changes made in the element after that will not affect the registered handlers

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand the `td` should be clickable only once, so what you need is [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$("td").one('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass("done");
    if (blue) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
        blue = false;
    } else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
        blue = true;
    }
});
```

or using event delegation with not done filter

```
$("table").on('click', 'td:not(.done)', function () {
    $(this).addClass("done");
    if (blue) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
        blue = false;
    } else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
        blue = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't really need to add the class, then you can add a handler to the click event using "one" method, that way, it will be executed only once

http://api.jquery.com/one/

```
    $("td").one("click",(function(){
        if(blue){
            $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
            blue = false;
        } else {
            $(this).css("background-color", "red");
            blue = true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use delegation for that, so selector for target is evaluated each time you click:

```
$('table').on('click','td:not(.done)', function(){
        $(this).addClass("done");
        if (blue) {
            $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
            blue = false;
        } else {
            $(this).css("background-color", "red");
            blue = true;
        }
});
```